# BQ Aquaris E4.5 - USB network adapter via OTG

Tags: networking, ubuntu-touch, hardware, phone

I tried to get a network connection via an OTG USB ethernet adapter, but it does not seem to work OOTB. The very same ethernet adapter (from Apple, 2010) works with the Nexus 7 (2013) and Nexus 5 under Android 5.1 OOTB.
Does anybody have experience with those adaptors on the BQ Aquaris E4.5?
TIA,
M.

Comment: Any updates on this? Did you find an OTG ethernet device that works or has drivers for the Aquaris E4.5?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it will not work, unless the kernel would be recompiled with driver enabled. Ubuntu touch by default shaves a lot of drivers (so much for being same linux as desktop) as it needs every MB to run unity. It is supposed that built in WiFi is enough for doing the 'conventional' stuff for using webapps(tweeting, fasebooking, and so on) or staring to UT calendar or calculating 1+1. Not cool by default. If you want to use UT devices for productivity you need to reconfigure and recompile the kernel. (the best instruction how to do it is here:

https://sturmflut.github.io/ubuntu/bq/2015/07/02/hacking-the-bq-part-4-building-and-booting-a-kernel/)